# How should I modify a Keras ResNet model to accept inputs with more than 3 channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I am using Keras with TF backend. Instead of giving just one image as input, I want to give two. Since all layers are convolutional (i don't care about the final predictions), I thought this should be fine, but there is a constraint on the inputs of Keras'resnet model and it only allows for exactly three channels as the input channel size. What's the cleanest way of modifying this? I want to able to load the pre-trained weights for this model and hence was hoping to make do with the existing APIs with minimal modifications.

Comment: A `siamese` newtork?

Comment: That's a great idea as well, but instead of fusing the activations of the two inputs later, I want to fuse them in the beginning itself and get the activation for the penultimate layer (before classification) for this combined tensor.

Comment: just train the layer where you change the channel and load existing weights in the rest of the layer's

Comment: Then you have to train it in that way. Although I strongly recommend to go with siamese as of now